# Base2 to Base10 converter won't work with very large numbers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, binary, decimal

If the user inputs a very large number in binary the output shows a 0, how would I go about modifying this function to work with larger numbers?

```
{ 
    // Binary to Decimal converter function

    int bin_Dec(int myInteger)
    {
    int output = 0;
    for(int index=0; myInteger > 0; index++ )
    {
    if(myInteger %10 == 1)
        {
            output += pow(2, index); 
        }
    myInteger /= 10;
    }
    return output;
    }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    { // start main

    int myNumber;

    // get number from user

    cout << "Enter a binary number, Base2: "; // ask for number 
    cin >> myNumber;

    //print conversion

    cout << "Base10: " << bin_Dec(myNumber) << endl; // print conversion
    system("pause");

    } // end of main
}
```

Comment: `999` isn't a base 2 number.  `1000` is, and it works with your code.  What is the real problem you're having?  What specifically is the input that didn't work for you?

Comment: not sure what you're asking here... the program expects you to enter a *binary* number. Entering `999` just won't work. By the way, the way it is written, the highest binary number it will accept is 1111111111 (=10 digits). The highest number it'll output will be 2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop taking your "binary number" as an `int`.  An int is limited in size; the max is generally about 2 billion, which is 10 digits.  When you're abusing digits as bits, that gives you a max of 10 *bits*, which equates to 1023.

Take a `string` instead.  You're not doing any useful math with the input; you're just using it as a string of digits anyway.

```
// oh, and unless you have good reason...this would be better unsigned.
// Otherwise your computer might catch fire when you specify a number larger
// than INT_MAX.  With an unsigned int, it's guaranteed to just lop off the
// high bits.
// (I may be overstating the "catch fire" part.  But the behavior is undefined.)
unsigned int bin_to_dec(std::string const &n) {
    unsigned int result = 0;
    for (auto it = n.begin(); it != n.end(); ++it) {
        result <<= 1;
        if (*it == '1') result |= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you have C++11, though, there's `std::stoi` and family (defined in `<string>`) which will do this for you when you specify base 2.  Unless you're reinventing the wheel for learning purposes, it'd be better to use them.

```
std::cout << "Base10: " << std::stoi(myNumberString, 0, 2) << '\n';
```

Comment: a side note: although the result is correct, I think it's more correct to use `result += 1;` operation instead of `result |= 1;`

Comment: Depends on how you consider it.  I consider it more "shifting in" a 1 or 0.  But X*2+1 is correct too.

Comment: BTW, the g++ 4.7.2 compiler at LWS doesn't seem to like your code, I can't figure why: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2OTOP6$4

Comment: You might need to specify `--std=c++0x` or `--std=c++11`.  `auto` is a C++11'ism.

Comment: It's with `-std=c++11`. The problem is with the shifting(`result << 1`). Replacing it with multiplication resolves the issue.

Comment: oooo...i see the problem.  `result << 1;` has no effect.  It should be `result <<= 1;`.  Fixing.